# Getting value null when click on GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener in Android

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA8BL.png)I am working on a map application where I am adding marker through latitude and longitude coming from JSON. Also other information are coming with each latitude and longitude. I have store this info into an array list. Marker is showing exact location but problem arises when I am trying to show this info into an custom dialog in Google marker click in respect of marker position, value is showing null. How to solve this problem?

**My MarkerHolder class**

```
public class MarkerHolder {
    public String bunch_jobName;
    public String addess;
    public String destiny;
    public String note;

    public MarkerHolder(String bunch_jobName, String addess, String destiny, String note) {
        bunch_jobName = bunch_jobName;
        addess  = addess;
        destiny = destiny;
        note = note;
    }
}

GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker){
        cal = new Dialog(activity);
        cal.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        cal.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        cal.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        cal.setContentView(R.layout.marker_popup_info);
        cal.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        TextView stops_name = cal.findViewById(R.id.tv_stops_name);
        TextView stops_addr = cal.findViewById(R.id.tv_stops_address);
        TextView stops_destination = cal.findViewById(R.id.tv_destiny);
        TextView stops_note = cal.findViewById(R.id.tv_note);
        MarkerHolder mHolder = markerHolderMap.get(marker.getId());


        stops_name.setText(mHolder.bunch_jobName);
        stops_addr.setText(mHolder.bunch_jobName);
        stops_destination.setText(mHolder.bunch_jobName);
        stops_note.setText(mHolder.bunch_jobName);

        cal.show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

With in JSON

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.position(new LatLng(location_lat1, location_longi1));

Marker marker = GoogleMap.addMarker(options);

MarkerHolder mHolder = new MarkerHolder(task_job_name,job_merchant,contact_no,task_address);
markerHolderMap.put(marker.getId(), mHolder);
```

Comment: post your crash related logcat and also use debugger to see where the app is crashing.

Comment: Actually there are not happened any crash issue.When I am print System.out.println("Value"+mHolder.bunch_jobName) in marker click it returns blank.Please find my attached screen shot.

Comment: It is not clear in your code where markerHolderMap is initialized. I will say again, use debugger to check what value your markerHolderMap is holding when you click your marker.

Comment: static HashMap<String, MarkerHolder> markerHolderMap = new HashMap<String, MarkerHolder>(); this is markerHolderMap initializetion

Comment: you should check 'why' your map is empty when you click on your marker, does the hashmap has any value? So thats why i am saying that you should use debugger, or post your whole code so that we can see what we doing incorrectly.